# sihouette score returns inconsistent number of sample

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using scikit's silhouette_score hierarchical clustering. I am not from data science background, or python. However i do know some other languages and do know how hierarchical clustering logic works. i was told to use the scikit's silhouette_score to calculate the silhouette score. this code returns an error of

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [149, 150]
```

The data used is csv, containing 151 rows with the first row as the data's type. So in total there is 150 datas.

here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage, fcluster
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score

iris = pd.read_csv("Iris.csv")

#iris hierarichal
iris_df = iris.iloc[:, 1:5]

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
plt.title("Iris Dendograms Average Method")

link = linkage(iris_df, method='average')

dend = dendrogram(link)
plt.show()

clusters = fcluster(link, 3, criterion='maxclust')

print(silhouette_score(link, clusters))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a problem here:

```
print(silhouette_score(link, clusters))
```

Change it and you're fine to go:

```
print(silhouette_score(X, clusters))
```

Please see [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html) for `silhouette_score`:

> X: array [n_samples_a, n_samples_a] if metric == “precomputed”, or, [n_samples_a, n_features] otherwise.
> Array of pairwise distances between samples, or a feature array.